# Irreducibility of $p(x)=x^4-4x^2+8x+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$- Dummit Foote Abstract algebra $9.4.10$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Question is :

> Prove that the polynomial $p(x)=x^4-4x^2+8x+2$ is irreducible over the quadratic field $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$. [Hint : first use the method of proposition $11$ for the U.F.D $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$(cf.Exercise $8$, Section $8.1$) to show that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a root of $p(x)$ then $\alpha$ is a divisor of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ . Conclude that $\alpha$ must be $\pm 1,\pm \sqrt{-2}$ or $\pm 2$ and hence show that $p(x)$ has no linear factor over $F$. Show similarly that $p(x)$ is not the product of quadratics with coefficients in $F$.]

What I have done so far is :

Suppose $\alpha \in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a root of $p(x)=x^4-4x^2+8x+2$ we would then have :

$p(\alpha)=\alpha^4-4\alpha^2+8\alpha+2=0\Rightarrow 2=\alpha(-\alpha^3+4\alpha-8)$

i.e., $\alpha$ is a divisor of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

so, I have **used the method of proposition $11$ for the U.F.D $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$(cf.Exercise $8$, Section $8.1$) to show that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a root of $p(x)$ then $\alpha$ is a divisor of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$**

I do not understand why does he mentioned that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is U.F.D and all... I do not use that at all... It is unnecessarily confusing me or i am unnecessarily getting confused..
hint is actually misleading me :(

Now, I have to prove that **$\alpha$ must be $\pm 1,\pm \sqrt{-2}$ or $\pm 2$**

i.e., suppose I have $2=ab$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ then, $N(2)=N(ab)\Rightarrow 4=N(a)N(b)$

i.e.,$N(a)=1\text{ or }2\text{ or } 4$ i.e., $p^2+2q^2=1\text{ or }2\text{ or } 4$ for $a=p+\sqrt{-2}q$

- $p^2+2q^2=1\Rightarrow p=\pm 1 \Rightarrow a=\pm 1$
- $p^2+2q^2=2\Rightarrow q=\pm 1\Rightarrow a=\pm\sqrt{-2}$
- $p^2+2q^2=4\Rightarrow p=\pm 2\Rightarrow a=\pm 2$

Once I prove that those are the only divisors then I would consider :

- $p(1)=(1)^4-4(1)^2+8(1)+2\neq 0$
- $p(-1)=(-1)^4-4(-1)^2+8(-1)+2\neq 0$
- $p(\sqrt{-2})=(\sqrt{-2})^4-4(\sqrt{-2})^2+8(\sqrt{-2})+2\neq 0$
- $p(-\sqrt{-2})=(-\sqrt{-2})^4-4(-\sqrt{-2})^2+8(-\sqrt{-2})+2\neq 0$
- $p(2)=(2)^4-4(2)^2+8(2)+2\neq 0$
- $p(-2)=(-2)^4-4(-2)^2+8(-2)+2\neq 0$

So, no divisor of $2$ is a root..

Thus $p(x)$ do not have a root in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

suppose I have something like :

$$x^4-4x^2+8x+2=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^4+(a+c)x^3+(b+d+ac)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd$$

But then, $bd=2\Rightarrow \text { b,d  are  a divisors of 2 in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-2}$}$

But then we have seen that **only divisors of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-2}$ are $\pm 1,\pm \sqrt{-2}$ or $\pm 2$**

So, only possibilities are

- $x^4-4x^2+8x+2=(x^2+ax\pm 1)(x^2+cx\mp 2)$
- $x^4-4x^2+8x+2=(x^2+ax\pm \sqrt{-2})(x^2+cx\mp \sqrt{-2})$

But these are not possible...

This only tells that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ but then how do i show this is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ I was expecting gauss lemma to help but it only works for integers and rationals...

So, please help me to clear this..

Thank you...

P.S : Proposition $11$ is Rational root theorem and Exercise $8$ is that ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ is an Euclidean domain.

Comment: I guess (haven't checked) that you can do the rest by checking that a factorization of the form
$$p(x)=(x^2-\alpha x+\beta)(x^2+\alpha x+2/\beta)$$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, $\beta\mid 2$ does not work.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes sir, I was hoping that to come smoothly... Actually i am typing that.... Unknowingly i have clicked that post button and it got posted in half way.... I would keep this deleted and then post once i am done...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir, It is saying that i can not edit the post once i delete it... so.. please wait for just $2$ minutes i would complete this...

Comment: No worries. If those calculations go through, you probably should post them as an answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir, I have done what all i could... please have a look at that...

Comment: Doesn't Gauss' lemma work because $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is Euclidean?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Yes sir, I could see that now... How could i miss that... Gauss lemma also holds for U.F.D.. May be that is the reason why he is mentioning $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$  is a U.F.D.. I was getting irritated unnecessarily... sometimes saying something more about the question would reduce the sweetness i guess :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gauss lemma does work for  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

- $f(x)=x^4-4x^2+8x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ so it is irreducible  in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$